# postgresql - split column to row based on string length

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I'm new to the database, so please pardon me if this is basis. I have a list of product codes merged in a column/cell of a table for each product type like below

```
codes                | type
----------------------------------
SM01SM02SG41GD2ZDM5  | Medicine 
SN01ML2 ML2H         | Food
```

I need such data to be converted as below (per every 4 character of code a new row has be constructed) through sql in Posrgresql database.

```
code | type      | item-number
----------------------------------
SM01 | Medicine  | 1
SM02 | Medicine  | 2
SG41 | Medicine  | 3
GD2Z | Medicine  | 4
DM5  | Medicine  | 5
SN01 | Food      | 2
ML2  | Food      | 3
ML2H | Food      | 1
```

Any advise/assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: I think the item-number for `DM5 ` should be 5 ? (And the order order the `Food` items seems wrong ?)

Comment: My bad... Your understanding is correct. Item# should be 5 for code DM5

Answer (score 0):

A recursive cte can do this:

```
WITH recursive cte as (
   SELECT 'SM01SM02SG41GD2ZDM5' as codes, 'Medicine' as type
   union all
   SELECT 'SN01ML2 ML2H', 'Food' 
),
cte1 as (
   SELECT SUBSTRING(codes,1,4) as code, cte.type as "type", 1 as item_number
   from cte
   
   union all
   
   select  substring(codes,item_number*4+1,4), cte1.type, item_number+1 
   from cte1
   inner join cte on cte.type=cte1.type
   where item_number < length(codes)/4+1
      )
select * 
from cte1
where code<>''
order by type desc, item_number
;
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b9bbeeef55fdeaf96429fe4170e3b2dd)

output:

| code | type | item_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SM01 | Medicine | 1 |
| SM02 | Medicine | 2 |
| SG41 | Medicine | 3 |
| GD2Z | Medicine | 4 |
| DM5 | Medicine | 5 |
| SN01 | Food | 1 |
| ML2 | Food | 2 |
| ML2H | Food | 3 |

Comment: Thank you so much @Luuk . Provided solution indeed fulfills the need. Your help is much appreciated!!! :)